# Valgrind invalid read of size 8 when printing out a character array

Tags: c, pointers, valgrind

I am trying to print out an array of characters, but valgrind is giving an invalid read message when I try to print out the lines. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void printLines (char *ptArray[]);
char line1[] = "black yummy wolfberry";
char line2[] = "Nate is cute";
char line3[] = "hi there friend";
char line4[] = "abcd";

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  char **ptArray = calloc(4, sizeof(char *)); // Line 28 when calling calloc
  ptArray[0] = line1;
  ptArray[1] = line2;
  ptArray[2] = line3;
  ptArray[3] = line4;

  printLines(ptArray); // Line 34 when printLines is called

  free(ptArray);
  return 0;
}

void printLines (char *ptArray[]){
  char **a = ptArray;
  while(*a != NULL){   // Line 232 when invalid read occurs
    printf("%s\n", *a);
    a++;
  }
}
```

Here is the error message:

```
==12029== Invalid read of size 8
==12029==    at 0x40110C: printLines (textsort2.c:232)
==12029==    by 0x4008F2: main (textsort2.c:36)
==12029==  Address 0x5204060 is 0 bytes after a block of size 32 alloc'd
==12029==    at 0x4C2FB55: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==12029==    by 0x400883: main (textsort2.c:28)
```

Anybody knows how to fix this? I appreciate all your help!

Comment: You don't nullterminate your array.

Comment: @tkausl May I ask how to do that?? Do I make the array one size larger and add a null value at the end?

Comment: Yes, `char **ptArray = calloc(5, sizeof *ptArray);`  5 not 4.  `ptArray[4] = 0;`

Comment: @chux Thanks chux! Is this always the case for an array of pointers, to terminate with a null?

Comment: No, but  `printLines()` is looking for a final pointer to NULL.  Code could have called `printLines_withCount(ptArray, 4);`

Comment: Also (and perhaps the main problem?)  you declare a variable ptArray in the printlines function that masks the argument.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Do not see this, please expand.

Comment: @chux, nevermind, didn't see the =

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code iterates past the 4 allocated pointers look for a *null pointer*.

```
  while(*a != NULL){   // Line 232 when invalid read occurs
    printf("%s\n", *a);
    a++;
  }
```

Code should allocate a 5th and assigned it `NULL`.

```
  // char **ptArray = calloc(4, sizeof(char *));
  char **ptArray = calloc(5, sizeof *ptArray);
  ptArray[0] = line1;
  ...
  ptArray[3] = line4;
  ptArray[4] = NULL;
```

---

Alternate, pass count

```
void printLinesN(char *ptArray[], size_t count){
  for (size_t i = 0; i<count; i++) {
    printf("%s\n", ptArray[i]);
  }
}  

// Call example
// printLines(ptArray);
printLinesN(ptArray, 4);
```

Comment: Thanks chux! By the way how do I do a printLines with count?

Comment: That is super helpful !! Thanks again <3 <3